# Converting string to 'timestamp with timezone' in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a string "2016-07-21T21:30:47.492+0000" I want to save it in DB in a column  that has the datatype 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE'. Kindly suggest the solution.

This is what I did:

```
final SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSX");
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
final Date d1 = mdyFormat.parse(strDate);
final String mdx = sdf.format(d1);
```

Comment: Which database software are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It sounds like you should basically parse the string, probably to a `java.util.Date` or `java.time.Instant`, then convert to a `java.sql.Timestamp` and use that in a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I tried to parse , but got the Parser exception.

Comment: This is what I did :

final SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSX");
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    final Date d1 = mdyFormat.parse(strDate);

    final String mdx = sdf.format(d1);

Comment: What happens if you remove two of  the `S` characters from your date format?  You've only got three digits for the milliseconds.

Comment: I did something like this and it removed the error :

final SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    final Date d1 = mdyFormat.parse(strDate);

    final String mdx = sdf.format(d1);

    System.out.println(mdx);

However with this I am getting 2016-07-22T03:00:47.492+05 as the o/p which is not the one I should get.

Comment: Is the issue with the output that you were expecting `+0530` for the timezone?  Otherwise, I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: @DavidWallace  Problem solved to a great extent with this :

final SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    final Date d1 = mdyFormat.parse(strDate);

    final String mdx = sdf.format(d1);

    System.out.println(mdx);

The o/p that I am getting is "2016-07-21T21:30:47.492Z" . But while saving it into the DB, it is giving me 'not a valid month' error.

Comment: @DavidWallace Secondly here the sample string that I have used is of the UTC timezone, but I may get any timezone value. How do I make sure I get the o/p according to the timezone provided?

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you save it into the database.  So I have no idea what you're doing wrong.

Comment: update tablename set column1= '2016-07-21T21:30:47.492Z' where column2= value;

here column1 is of the type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Comment: I really think you should use the advice that @JonSkeet gave in his earlier comment - use a `PreparedStatement` with a `java.sql.Timestamp` as one of its parameters.  If you don't want to go that way, you should look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm for information about how to format the SQL literal that you need for a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in Oracle.

Comment: @DavidWallace I changed the approach :

On DB side datatype taken : varchar2 
Data in DB : "2016-07-21T21:30:47.492+0000"

Now on the  Java side , I want to fetch the Date as 07212016 , Time as 213047 and the timezone as UTC.

I know I am being troublesome, but I don't even know the basics of Date Time stuff.

Comment: I guess that's a third approach.  I still think Jon Skeet's idea would have been worth pursuing.

Comment: I can't go ahead with Jon Skeet's approach since I am not using a single query to save things in DB. The procedure is written for the same.

Answer (score 4):

You are using troublesome old classes now supplanted by java.time classes.

Here is how to follow the advice given by Jon Skeet posted in a comment on the Question.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `OffsetDateTime`

You can parse that input string as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-07-21T21:30:47.492+0000" );
```

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later, you may be able to pass/fetch to SQL via the `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` methods. If not, convert to the old java.sql type.

Converting requires an `Instant` object. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a more basic building-block class in java.time, lacking the flexibility of an `OffsetDateTime`. The `Instant` class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to nanoseconds. Extract an `Instant` from that `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

Pass the `Instant` to a new method added to the old java.sql class.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

Then call the `PreparedStatement::setTimestamp` and `ResultSet::getTimestamp` methods.

```
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( 1 , ts );
…
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 1 );
```

After fetching a `java.sql.Timestamp`, immediately convert to a java.time class, `Instant`. Use the java.sql classes only where direct support for java.time types is lacking in your JDBC driver, and even then, minimize your use of the java.sql classes. Do your business logic work in java.time.

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

## Confusing class names

Do not confuse the two old `Date` classes bundled with Java. The `java.util.Date` represents a date *and* a time-of-day. A `java.sql.Date` is intended to represent only a date-only value without a time-of-day (but confusing actually does have a time-of-day due to it being a clumsy hack of an awkward class design).

Avoid the `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` classes entirely. And minimize your use of the `java.sql.Date`/`.Time`/`.Timestamp` classes as discussed above.

Comment: Your answer saved me!!

Comment: @GauravKhare Good, I'm glad. Date-time handling is tricky work. You can learn more by studying more Q&A on Stack Overflow. Look especially for Answers by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), and for Answers mentioning java.time.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting those posts, and you are correct date time handling is really very tricky at least for me.

Comment: Your example throws: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-07-21T21:30:47.492+0000' could not be parsed at index 23

Answer (score 0):

Your code is having one problem

```
 String strDate = "2016-07-21T21:30:47.492+0000"; 
        final SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSX");
     // include `T` as well

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    final Date d1;
            try {
                d1 = mdyFormat.parse(strDate);
// to add time zone you  can use below line 
//  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                String mdx = sdf.format(d1);
                System.out.println(mdx);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {

            }
```

Output without `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`

`22-07-2016`

Output with `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`

`21-07-2016`

`TimeZone.getDefault()` gets the system's default timezone.

Comment: Thanks AJ. This corrected the date. But I am still getting the output as 2016-07-21T21:30:47.492Z. Moreover while saving this in DB, I am getting the  'not a valid month' error. 
P.S - On the DB side, the type is TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE